# How to append a jQuery variable value inside the .html tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have a jquery variable which contains html tags to create checkboxes dynamically.
Now as per my need i have to add this variable inside the .html tag of jquery to show the checkboxes inside the dialogue box ..Also my .html contains form tag to include the checkboxes code inside the form..

Here is my variabel which contains the html tags..

```
var chbx=<input type="checkbox"   id="Mumbai" name="Mumbai" value="Mumbai" />Mumbai<br />
<input type="checkbox"   id=" Delhi" name=" Delhi" value=" Delhi" /> Delhi<br />\
<input type="checkbox"   id=" Bangalore" name=" Bangalore" value=" Bangalore" /> Bangalore<br />
```

And here is my .html tag containing form ..

```
var $dialog = $('<div></div>').html("<form id='myform'>" +chbx+ "</form>")
        .dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            title: 'Select Sites',
            buttons: {
                "Submit": function() {  $('form#myform').submit();},
                "Cancel": function() {$(this).dialog("close");}
            }
        });
```

i tried to append the variable like +chbx+ but its not happening and showing empty dialogue box..

Comment: you should insert html into specific selector/id/class/object. I'm not sure though but what does $('<div></div>') mean!! Try my answer, i've simply inserted the html with the <div> id.

Comment: @codeSpy $('<div></div>') is my selector and i need to insert the chbx inside this only

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**HTML :**

```
<div id="myDiv">
    <form id="myForm">
    </form> 
</div>
```

**jQuery :**

```
var chbx='<input type="checkbox" id="Mumbai" name="Mumbai" value="Mumbai" />Mumbai<br /> <input type="checkbox" id=" Delhi" name=" Delhi" value=" Delhi" /> Delhi<br/><input type="checkbox" id=" Bangalore" name=" Bangalore" value=" Bangalore"/>Bangalore<br />';

$("#myDiv form#myForm").html(chbx);

//to insert dynamically created form 
$("#myDiv").html("<form id='dynamicForm'>" +chbx + "'</form>");
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/codeSpy/XwDUk/)

Comment: thank you very much sir for your response please sir tell me how can i use this code inside this line  $dialog = $('<div></div>').html('<form id="myform" action="">' + chbx + '</form>')

Comment: i tried to insert var $dialog = $('<div></div>').html("<form id='myform'>" +chbx+ "</form>") but this is also showing nothing in the dialogue box

Comment: please see sir i updated post with my actual code for dilaogue box

Comment: This should help you to add a form in your dialog.

http://jsbin.com/aqaji3/1/edit

Comment: is there any disadvantages if we use long html in jquery variable?

Comment: i think there is one extra Apostrophe in `"<form id='dynamicForm'>" +chbx + "'</form>"`

Answer (score 3):

See this [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/modaloda/VkV5K/)

HTML

```
<div id="products"></div>
```

JS

```
var someone = {
"name":"Mahmoude Elghandour",
"price":"174 SR",
"desc":"WE Will BE WITH YOU"
 };
 var name = $("<div/>",{"text":someone.name,"class":"name"
});

var price = $("<div/>",{"text":someone.price,"class":"price"});
var desc = $("<div />", {   
"text": someone.desc,
"class": "desc"
});
$("#products").fadeIn(1500);
$("#products").append(name).append(price).append(desc);
```